# Sublime Text 2 multiple selection at boundaries of selection (Mac OS X)

Tags: selection, sublimetext2

Say I have a the word "two" selected selected on a line like:

one `two` three

Is there a key combination to create a multiple selection with a cursor at both ends of the previous selection like this (in which the | characters represent cursors):

one |two| three

I'm looking for something like the command-shift-L feature, but it needs to work on a single line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a shortcut for this. It was `Ctrl+Shift+K`. It's still in [the docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection):

> Given a selected block of text, Ctrl+Shift+K will split it into two selections, one for each end.

It doesn't look like this exists anymore, but I wish they would bring it back.